# How to display the image retrieved from database?

Tags: hibernate, blob

[image]

Here the  site image is blob data type and i tried to retrive them and i am finding difficult to display the image in jsp page .
I am using hibernate for my development .
[image]
Here you can see the response from the database when i try to retrieve it.
Could anyone tell me how to display them in jsp Pages??It could be very useful

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please can you include the text of your issues in your question, where they are visible and searchable in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write one controller method which will read the image from the server like below and return back to calling environment i.e. browser.

Controller code :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getUserImage/{id}")
public void getUserImage(HttpServletResponse response , @PathVariable("id") int id) throws IOException{

 response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
  byte[] buffer = imageService.getImage(id).getUserImage();
  InputStream in1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
  IOUtils.copy(in1, response.getOutputStream());        
}
```

JSP code :

```
<img src="getUserImage/1"/>
```

Refer [spring-mvc-image-media-data](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-image-media-data)